# How do I capitalize all keys in a JSON array?

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm reading a `file.json` into memory. It's an array of objects, sample:

```
[
{"id":123123,"language":"ja-JP","location":"Osaka"}
,{"id":33332,"language":"ja-JP","location":"Tokyo"}
,{"id":31231313,"language":"ja-JP","location":"Kobe"}
]
```

I want to manipulate certain keys in this JSON file, so that they start with uppercase. Meaning

`"language"` becomes `"Language"` each time it's found. What I've done so far  is to make a struct representing each object, as such:

```
type sampleStruct struct {
    ID                   int    `json:"id"`
    Language             string `json:"Language"`
    Location             string `json:"Location"`
}
```

Here, I define the capitalization. Meaning, `id` shouldn't be capitalized, but `location` and `language` should.

Rest of the code is as such:

```
func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("Missing filename parameter.")
        return
    }

    translationfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    fileIsValid := isValidJSON(string(translationfile))

    if !fileIsValid {
        fmt.Println("Invalid JSON format for: ", os.Args[1])
        return
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't read file: ", os.Args[1])
        panic(err)
    }
}


func isValidJSON(str string) bool {
    var js json.RawMessage
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &js) == nil
}

// I'm unsure how to iterate through the JSON objects and only uppercase the objects matched in my struct here. 
func upperCaseSpecificKeys()
// ...
```

Desired output, assuming the struct represents the whole data object, transform each key as desired:

```
[
{"id":123123,"Language":"ja-JP","Location":"Osaka"}
,{"id":33332,"Language":"ja-JP","Location":"Tokyo"}
,{"id":31231313,"Language":"ja-JP","Location":"Kobe"}
]
```

Comment: decode it using a struct matching lowercase keys. Copy the data to a struct that is encoding to capitalized keys, output json encoded data of those new struct.

Comment: I see where you're going with it, I had the same thoughts, I'm unsure of how to implement it properly. If you have a link to any code samples or such I'd be grateful :)

Comment: From the docs: "To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match **but also accepting a case-insensitive** match". i.e. https://play.golang.org/p/1vv8PaQUOfg

Comment: @mkopriva Post that as an answer.

Comment: @mkopriva I took inspiration from your sample and it worked very well. Please do post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation on [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) says (with added emphasis):

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object
>   keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its
>   tag), preferring an exact match **but also accepting a case-insensitive
>   match**

See example here: https://play.golang.org/p/1vv8PaQUOfg

Comment: If I may ask: What would be the way to overwrite the file using `ioutil` after it is formatted? I can `fmt.Println` and it looks right in the console, so thanks for that. But how do I overwrite the file after, from my example?

Comment: Just like you use ReadFile, you can use WriteFile, passing it the converted bytes.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to implement custom marshal method, although not very flexible:

```
type upStruct struct {
    ID       int `json:"id"`
    Language string
    Location string
}

type myStruct struct {
    ID       int    `json:"id"`
    Language string `json:"language"`
    Location string `json:"location"`
}

func (m myStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(upStruct(m))
}
....
func main() {
    var mySArr []myStruct

    // 1. Unmarshal the input
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJson), &mySArr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Input: \n%+v\n", mySArr)

    // 2. Then, marshal it using our custom marshal method
    val, err := json.Marshal(mySArr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Output: \n%v\n", string(val))
}
```

Link to working code: https://play.golang.org/p/T4twqPc34k0

Thanks to [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva)

Comment: btw since Go 1.8 or 1.9? tags don't matter when converting struct types. So `upStruct(m)` will work just fine and you don't need the spell out the fields. (https://play.golang.org/p/T4twqPc34k0)